# Mysterious message

Tags: messages

I received a response from a friend via iMessage asking if I were going to call this evening and whether I had fun? When I asked what they were talking about they stated it was in response to a conversation sent last week...they sent a screen shot and it appears as though (last weeks dates included) that my iPhone sent old messages, however those messages were not on my end. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, if someone has possession of your carrier account/your phone number. Talk to your carrier immediately.

Comment: Is it possible that he inserted old messages into the iMessage conversation? Is that possible? I've also had other issues such as maps app opening and showing my location without me physically touching my phone.

Comment: Jordan, sounds like something's been hacked into. I recommend calling Apple immediately. Head over to http://getsupport.apple.com and call them from there.

Comment: They have a very friendly and fast support team.